# Issue with passing attributes between classes in python

Tags: python, class

Ive made these classes below and I'm trying to have a tile in the game present a text based on an attribute in another class. I keep getting this error.
File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\Game.idea\Girls.py", line 20, in not_interested
    return (self.interest < 10)
AttributeError: 'GirlTile' object has no attribute 'interest'

```
class Girls():
    def __init__(self):
        self.girlnames = ["Lucy", "Cindy", "April", "Allison", "Heather", "Andrea", "Brittany", "Jessica", "Lane", "Lauren", "Sabrina","Chelsea","Amber"]
        self.name = random.choice(self.girlnames)
        self.height = random.randrange(60, 72)
        self.age = random.randrange(18, 25)
        self.number = self.new_number()
        self.interest = 0

        def not_interested(self):
            return (self.interest < 10)

from Girls import Girls

class GirlTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.enemy = Girls()
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def intro_text(self):
        self.stance = Girls.not_interested(self)
        if self.stance:
            print("Hey whats up")
```

Comment: `GirlTile` class is not the same as the `Girls` class, only `Girls` have `interest`. You are passing an instance of `GirlTile` to `Girls.not_interested()` - I assume you meant `self.enemy.not_interested()`.

Comment: Just updated it to show the line

Comment: You need an instance of `Girls`, if `self.enemy` is not the correct instance then presumably you need an argument to `intro_text(self, girl)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `not_interested` is an instance-level method, but you are trying to call it with a class (`Girls`). And the call is sort of "working" because you are passing the `GirlTile` instance in the call -- hence the error that the `GirlTile` has no `interest` attribute (because it does not).

Maybe you intended this instead?

```
def intro_text(self):
    # Use an actual Girl instance to call not_interested().
    self.stance = self.enemy.not_interested()
    ...
```

Comment: ahhhhh yes that makes perfect sense! Much appreciated.